# How to SET fileinfo version to a PS1 file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, version, fileinfo

I have a PowerShell script named myscript.ps1 on a remote server.

I would like to know what is the version of this file. 
Unfortunately this command gives me nothing : 
`(Get-Item "C:\myscript.ps1").VersionInfo.FileVersion`

My question is : is there a way to add some information regarding the version of the script or else ? If yes, how please ?

My end goal is to check if the running script is the latest version otherwise download latest version on remote server and execute.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you're going to find that information there unless it was set.  I usually see that info in things like DLLs.

If it were me, and I was looking to see if a file was different (a script or otherwise) I would use the `Get-FileHash` commandlet instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set FileVersionInfo in .Net, so you will always get a null value when you check the FileVersionInfo on your PowerShell script. What you may want to do instead is to check the `LastWriteTime` property to see if the file on the server is newer than what you have locally.